# Can a father structure his estate's inheritance to his children & one son-in-law in set percentages?

Tags: law, estate-planning, will

In a will from father to 3 daughters (I don't have a son), I can make a will  giving equal shares to my 3 daughters.  But, one of my son-in-law is giving me 50% of the total cost of the flat to purchase the same.

Can I add his name also in the **will** along with my 3 daughters? His share will be 50% and the rest of the 50% would belong to my three daughters sharing equally i.e. 1/3  each.

Arithmetically 50% in favor of only one son-in-law, and 16.333% each in favor of 3 daughters. Totaling to 100% to be divided as mentioned above.

Can I add the name of my son-in-law who has contributed the amount for the purchase of the flat? Is it OK, in the will?

Comment: What country? Rules & Law would vary.

Comment: This is a legal question, not a financial one, and I vote to close.

Answer (score 6):

In most countries this should't be an issue you can make such or similar provision. Its best to talk to a lawyer to get the wording right.

Comment: Dheer is correct; seek a lawyer. This sounds very straight-forward, and shouldn't take the lawyer very long at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a will to offer whatever fraction of your assets you wish.

To handle this for a longer duration, I'd suggest specifying alternate beneficiaries. Be clear, if your Son-in-law passes before you do, who gets that portion? If your daughters plan to marry or are married, how will their inheritance pass?

A bit of extra thought can make the time you should spend grieving be just that, and not an urgent call to the lawyer with updates.